# Boundedness of an operator with kernel

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $K(x,y)$ be measurable in $\mathbb{R}^2.$  Suppose there is a positive, measurable (w.r.t Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$) $w(x)$ and $A\geq 0$ such that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \vert K(x,y) \vert w(y) dy \leq Aw(x) \quad \text{and} \quad \int_{-\infty}^\infty \vert K(x,y) \vert w(x) dx \leq Aw(y)$$
hold almost everywhere.  I'm trying to show that $Tf(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty K(x,y)f(y)dy$ is a bounded operator on $L_2(\mathbb{R}).$

Comment: This is a special case of [Schur's test.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_test) @NateEldredge's answer is basically the standard proof. This is actually one of very few general results in the theory of integral operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bound the quantity
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left| \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} K(x,y) f(y) \,dy \right|^2\,dx.$$
First note that it is certainly bounded by
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left| \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |K(x,y) f(y)| \,dy \right|^2\,dx.$$
Rewrite as
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left| \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left( \frac{|f(y)|}{w(y)} \cdot 1 \right) |K(x,y)| w(y) \,dy \right|^2\,dx.$$
Now, with the inner integral, apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality with respect to the measure $|K(x,y)| w(y)\,dy$.

After that you should see everything fall into place.

This trick shows up a lot in analysis: you have a relatively small stable of integral inequalities (triangle, Jensen, Hölder, Cauchy-Schwarz, Minkowski... there really aren't many others), but when applying them you can use some discretion as to what is the integrand and what is the measure.

Comment: Ahh I was trying to use Cauchy-Schwarz but I was running into trouble with the other factors. Thanks